# Performance tests between QueryDSL SQL vs JDBCTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, querydsl

I am trying to convince "the higher ups" to use querydsl sql for our persistence. But they prefer spring jdbctemplate, with the reason being it gives the best raw performance.

Performance is our primary requirement ofcourse. Which is why JPA isnt an option at all. Is the QueryDSL SQL overhead too much to knock it off from our options?

I wanted to know if there are any "recent" performance tests done to show how querydsl sql fares with jdbctemplate and jpa.

I came across [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/querydsl/Uri-JsQD6CE).
I want to know the relative performance of querydsl sql when compared against jdbctemplate and a jpa implementation.

Comment: A bit like _"Assembler (or C) is fastest."_ You'll never convince them pro QueryDSL unless there are use-cases that benefit from built-in intelligence. So do some rewrites, maybe you'll find some things: errors in SQL, short notation, optimisations in QueryDSL, resulting SQL.

Comment: I understand that it comes down to tradeoffs between raw performance and developer friendliness (maintainability). What I want to prove (or I am expecting) is that QueryDSL SQL does provide considerably better performance than JPA/ORM and is only "slightly" outperformed by JDBCTemplate. I am in search of some facts/figures for that. In the meantime, I am trying out some tests myself too.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have done some performance tests to compare the overhead/performance comparison between querydsl and jdbctemplate.

Here is what I did
 1. Created a spring boot project which uses querydsl and jdbctemplate
 2. Created 2 end points, 1 for using querydsl and another for jdbctemplate.
 3. The querydsl configuration uses the spring boot autoconfigured datasource to configure its SQLQueryFactory.
 4. JdbcTemplate is also autoconfigured with the same autoconfigured datasource.
 5. There are 2 implementations of a similary query in the repository, one uses querydsl and the other uses jdbctemplate. The query is relatively complex and consists of couple of inner joins and where clauses.
 6. The Service methods has a for loop and calls the repository method in each iteration. No. of iterations is configurable and has been set to 100,000 iterations.
 7. System.nanoTime() is used around the service method in the controller to calculate the time it took to execute that many iterations of the repository method.
 8. JdbcTemplate took an average of 800ms to execute 100,000 repository calls.
 9. Querydsl took an average of 5000ms to execute 100,000 repository calls.
**10. Observation: Querydsl is 6 times slower than JdbcTemplate for the same query. The overhead is presumably in the query serialization of querydsl.**

QueryDSL Repository Implementation

```
List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
Customer customerObj = null;
List<Tuple> customerTuples =queryFactory.select(customer.firstName,customer.status,customer.customerId).
                                from(customer).innerJoin(customerChat).on(customer.customerId.eq(customerChat.senderId)).
                                innerJoin(customerChatDetail).on(customerChat.chatDetailId.eq(customerChatDetail.chatDetailId)).
                                where(customerChatDetail.isRead.eq(true).and(customer.status.eq(true))).fetch();

    for (Tuple row : customerTuples) {
        customerObj = new Customer();
      customerObj.setFirstName(row.get(customer.firstName));
      customerObj.setStatus( row.get(customer.status));
      customerObj.setCustomerId(row.get(customer.customerId));
      customers.add(customerObj);
    }
return customers;
```

JdbcTemplate Implementation

```
List<Customer> customers = this.jdbcTemplate.query(
            "select first_name,status,customer_id from customer inner join v_customer_chat on customer.customer_id=v_customer_chat.sender_id inner join v_customer_chat_detail on v_customer_chat.chat_detail_id = v_customer_chat_detail.chat_detail_id where v_customer_chat_detail.is_read = ? and customer.status = ?;",new Object[] {true, true},
            new RowMapper<Customer>() {
                public Customer mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                    Customer customer = new Customer();
                    customer.setFirstName(rs.getString("first_name"));
                    customer.setStatus(rs.getBoolean("status"));
                    customer.setCustomerId(rs.getLong("customer_id"));
                    return customer;
                }
            });
```

Basically I am trying to do the exact same thing with different libraries and measure which one incurs more overhead.
1. Execute a relatively complex query with joins.
2. Populate beans from the resultset.

I am using H2 In-memory database. The database holds just a couple of records for each table. And 1 result row that matches the query.

The method is executed in a for loop (1 lakh iterations). And time calculated with the help of System.nanoTime() around the loop.

Its a spring boot project with different end points (one for querydsl and another for jdbctemplate). The configuration for querydsl and queryfactory is done as follows

```
  @Autowired
public DataSource dataSource;

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
}

@Bean
public com.querydsl.sql.Configuration querydslConfiguration() {
    SQLTemplates templates = H2Templates.builder().build();
    com.querydsl.sql.Configuration configuration = new com.querydsl.sql.Configuration(templates);

    configuration.setExceptionTranslator(new SpringExceptionTranslator());

    return configuration;
}

@Bean
public SQLQueryFactory queryFactory() {
    Provider<Connection> provider = new SpringConnectionProvider(dataSource);
    return new SQLQueryFactory(querydslConfiguration(), provider);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Profile your app and see what is taking the time in the query. Is it the parsing and compilation of the query, or the query itself?

Are you writing queries that return the entire domain object or a subset of columns (using the JPA "select new BlaBlaDTO" type construct) ?

Have you considered using Spring Data JPA where you have full control over whether you want to use RAW SQL, named queries, or Spring Data JPAs method naming convention queries ?

Is your JDBC connection setup to cache prepared statements on the database side so that they only need to be prepared once for the same query with different parameters (this makes a huge difference) ?

Are you using a first and second level cache to improve server side performance ?

Picking raw JDBC as a preferred mechanism will end up being awful; complex queries, no dirty checking, no optimistic locking etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ammen.M if you are looking for performance in terms of database access (in JavaEE platform) the best option is pure [JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/), but everybody knows about its limitations and the extensive use of strings with native SQL. Spring Data, JPA, or QueryDSL, all of these frameworks offers to you others benefits like type safety, relational mapping between tables and Objects.

So if your team is really concerned about performance that should be your bet.